# Gossip encryption not working fine

Tags: consul

I have created a master token using the below command:

```
$ consul keygen
G74SM8N9NUc4meaHfA7CFg==
```

Then, I bootstrapped the server with the following `config.json`:

```
{
  "server": true,
  "datacenter": "consul",
  "data_dir": "/var/consul",
  "log_level": "INFO",
  "enable_syslog": true,
  "disable_update_check": true,
  "client_addr": "0.0.0.0",
  "bootstrap": true,
  "leave_on_terminate": true,
  "encrypt": "G74SM8N9NUc4meaHfA7CFg=="
}
```

The output of the bootstrap server is as follows:

```
     Node name: 'abcd'
    Datacenter: 'consul'
        Server: true (bootstrap: true)
   Client Addr: 0.0.0.0 (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, DNS: 8600, RPC: 8400)
  Cluster Addr: x.x.x.x (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302)
Gossip encrypt: true, RPC-TLS: false, TLS-Incoming: false
         Atlas: <disabled>
```

Then, I added a new server as a regular consul server which has the following `config.json`:

```
{
      "server": true,
      "datacenter": "consul",
      "data_dir": "/var/consul",
      "log_level": "INFO",
      "enable_syslog": true,
      "disable_update_check": true,
      "client_addr": "0.0.0.0",
      "bootstrap": false,
      "leave_on_terminate": true,
      "ui_dir": "/usr/local/bin/consul_ui",
      "check_update_interval": "0s",
      "ports": {
        "dns": 8600,
        "http": 8500,
        "https": 8700,
        "rpc": 8400,
        "serf_lan": 8301,
        "serf_wan": 8302,
        "server": 8300
      },
      "dns_config": {
        "allow_stale": true,
        "enable_truncate": true,
        "only_passing": true,
        "max_stale": "02s",
        "node_ttl": "30s",
        "service_ttl": {
          "*": "10s"
        }
      },
      "advertise_addr": "y.y.y.y",
      "encrypt": "G74SM8N9NUc4meaHfA7CFg==",
      "retry_join": [
        "x.x.x.x",
        "y.y.y.y"
      ]
    }
```

Note: Here, `x.x.x.x` is IP address of the bootstrap server, `y.y.y.y` is IP address of the regular server.

For testing purpose, I changed the encrypt key on one of the servers. And, when I do `consul members`, I can still see the all IPs which means that the servers are still able to communicate even with the different encrypt key. It seems that the gossip encryption is not working fine.

Answer (score 2):

A Consul instance will cache the initial key and re-use it. It is stored in the `serf` folder in the file `local.keyring`.

This is counter-intuitive, but it is [documented at least in one place together with the encrypt option](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html).

You'll need to delete this file and restart Consul in order to get the expected behaviour.

Comment: Hit this problem when using helm chart, and turning on gossip encryption for a Consul that is already running. Consul pods started to fail unable to elect a leader. I uninstalled/reinstalled based on this answer and it resolved the issue.